# Error with SqlCommand and connection in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have errors with this code, but cannot find the problem. Please help.

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Software Project\BakeryProject Pages\BakeryProject\Databases\Users.mdf; Integrated Security = True");

myConnection.Open();

string commandText = "INSERT INTO Table (Id, Username, First_name, Last_Name, Password, Client, Staff, Admin )";
commandText += "VALUES (1, 'JohnSmith', 'John', 'Smith', 'Pass1', 'Client');";

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", mID);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", mUsername);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_name", mNameFirst);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_name", mNameLast);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", mPassword);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client", mClient);

myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What errors are you getting specifically?  You're listing 8 columns, but you only have 6 values, maybe remove Staff and Admin?

Comment: One obvious problem is `commandText += "VALUES`. You must add a space before `commandText += " VALUES` it so it can be in the proper SQL format.

Comment: @granit No since there's a ")" before that the spaces is not needed.

Comment: @juharr Oh, yes, you're right.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: After correcting the Columns and values, there is a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Comment: @RossLeech when you come to this site with a question about a exception you need to click the "[Copy Exception Details to the clipboard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/)" then paste the entire text [in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43664673/edit) inside a code block so it keeps it's formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add params, but you never defined any in your query.  Perhaps this is what you meant:

```
string commandText = "INSERT INTO [Table] (Id, Username, First_name, Last_Name, Password, Client) ";
       commandText += "VALUES (@Id, @Username, @First_name, @Last_name, @Password, @Client);";

SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, myConnection);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", mID);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", mUsername);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_name", mNameFirst);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_name", mNameLast);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", mPassword);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client", mClient);

myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note: I've also removed the `Staff` and `Admin` columns from your script as they don't have a param mentioned below.  This should give you a point in the right direction though.

As a side-note, it's much easier to declare queries in C# by using a string literal.  This way, you don't have to mess with the `+=` and weird spacing issues that come from it:

```
string commandText =
@"
Insert  [Table] (Id, Username, First_name, Last_Name, Password, Client)
Values  (@Id, @Username, @First_name, @Last_name, @Password, @Client);      
";
```

Comment: An error was thrown after this " An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'. "   
 Any ideas?

Comment: @RossLeech Use the actual name of your table...

Comment: The table name is Table, could it be anything else?

Comment: @Siyual The `Into` keyword was missing so I added that in.

Comment: @RossLeech Please do not name your database objects as reserved keywords. Not only can it get very confusing, as it is now, but you could run into a whole host of weird - and hard to diagnose - bugs down the road. Give your table a meaningful name, related to the data it is expected to store. If, however, you still decide to go with `table` as your table name, you need to explicitly use the following notation:`[table]`. This will mark your value as an identifier, not a key word.

Comment: @YannickMeeus `Into` is 100% optional.

Comment: @RossLeech Updated the query - if your table's name is `Table` you need to escape it with square brackets.

Comment: @Siyual This is true for T-SQL, but not for every implementation of SQL. In the end, opinions are going to differ on this so I don't mind it not being there. It just feels *off* to me to not have it.

Comment: @YannickMeeus True, but this question is specifically tagged `[sql-server]`, so we're not talking about another DBMS that doesn't support it.